# How do you update the root view title in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex4.5, mxml, flexbuilder

Is there a way to update at runtime the root view title in Flex?

I tried something along the lines of:

`<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="{title}" activate="populateTitle()">`

with

`function populateTitle () {
  title = "updated!";
}`

... but the title isn't updating!

Comment: Just realized viewActivate is apparently the one to call... I'm not sure what activate does then.

Comment: You sure the title is bindable ?